# Video not playing in html page

Tags: video

I had given the following code to show a video as a part of my html page.

```
<video width="250px" controls>
<source src="mymovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="mymovie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

But the video is not playing. Can anyone help me out to solve this.

Comment: Try to give full path of video to src

Answer (score 0):

**Embedding media in your HTML document is trivial:**

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

This example plays a sample video, with playback controls, from the Theora web site.

Here is an example for embedding audio into your HTML document

```
<video src="/test/mov_bbb.mp4">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</video>
```

The src attribute can be a URL of the audio file or the path to the file on the local system.

**Give your local path properly**

source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)